# Printing decimal value instead of pointers

Tags: c, printf, dynamic-memory-allocation, realloc

I am using realloc to allocate some data into the memeory

i have no problem printing char array / char value but only decimal which i encounter problem

```
size_t N_att;
typedef struct student_struct {          
    char *name;
    int32_t     age; 
    int32_t     marks;  

} STUDENT;
STUDENT*STUDENTS;


STUDENTS= realloc(STUDENTS, (N_att + 3) * sizeof(*STUDENTS));
STUDENTS[N_att].name = "James";
STUDENTS[N_att++].age = 20;
STUDENTS[N_att+2].marks = 100;
STUDENTS[N_att] = (STUDENT) { NULL };

//testing to print the 1st entry only
printf("%s %d %d", STUDENTS[0].name, STUDENTS[0].age, STUDENTS[0].marks);
```

Output

```
James -8421540451 -8421540451
```

I have no idea what is the issue over here, it is printing what looks like to me the pointer of the value in the memory.
Correct me if i am in the wrong direction of printing decimal

Comment: use `temp` in realloc..otherwise if it fails..you have memory leak

Comment: Side note: all capital identifiers are reserved for macros by convention.

Comment: typo, corrected N_att + 2

Comment: Please show a [mcve], there is not enough code.

Comment: why are you expecting to get something in `N_att`? Are you writing there?

Comment: `STUDENTS[N_att++]` is also fishy. [MCVE] pleeease.

Comment: FWIW, you use indices N_att, N_att++ (which increments N_att) and then N_att+2 (which is original N_att+3). Why? Why do not all access the same struct?

Comment: Are the definitions inside of a function or at file scope? Do you initialize `STUDENTS` and `N_att` somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't given a minimal compilable example, so it's hard to tell what you did wrong in those invisible parts of code.

My guess is you do not initialize `N_att` variable, hence undefined result of `realloc()`.

Additionally you use three different expressions to calculate index to the `STUDENTS` array when assigning `"James"`, `20` and `100`, which seems quite weird... Those three assignments look like initializing a *single* structure; if it is so, all three should use the same index.

Comment: Please don't give guesses as answers. They are likely invalidated when/if question is clarified. Close question instead, and answer when it's been improved and reopened.

Comment: Not only N_atthas a problem. If N_att and STUDENTS are defined in a function, both are not initialized, feeding a "random" pointer into `realloc`

Comment: @Gerhardh That's precisely what I wrote: _'my guess is you do not initialize `N_att` variable'_...

Comment: Yes, but you didn't mention that `STUDENTS` has the same problem.

Comment: @Gerhardh There's lots of problems here, and it's useless to list them all. The most important, however, is neither `N_att` nor `STUDENTS` but  the lack of MCVE.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are initializing values to different indexes and printing with 0 index. Your code does look weird as CiaPan mentions in his comment. If you are looking to print the value of 0 index then you should use the same index.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

size_t N_att;
typedef struct student_struct
{
        char *name;
        int     age;
        int     marks;

} STUDENT;
STUDENT*STUDENTS;

int main()
{
        STUDENTS = realloc(STUDENTS, (N_att + 3) * sizeof(*STUDENTS));
        STUDENTS[N_att].name = "James"; // here you initialized in 0th index
        STUDENTS[N_att++].age = 20; // same here but N_att incremented by one
        STUDENTS[N_att+2].marks = 100; // here index is (updated index + 2 = 3)
        STUDENTS[N_att] = (STUDENT) { NULL }; // here you init it to null

        // Here you are printing 0 th index which has only "James" "20" 
        printf("%s %d %d\n", STUDENTS[0].name, STUDENTS[0].age, STUDENTS[0].marks);
}
```

**NOTE:-** check it again, output should be "James" "20" "garbage value"

Comment: Please check code with warnings enabled before posting. (Fixed it for you. ;-) )